# These dependencies were not found

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, fonts

I'm trying to import a css (modules-css) that is in the node_modules, and I fall into the following error:

**These dependencies were not found**

*** fonts/font.eot** 
*** fonts/font.svg** 
 
*** fonts/font.ttf** 
 
*** fonts/font.woff** 
 
*** fonts/font.woff2**

(Package is installed)

I'm importing this way:

```
import { alert } from 'myfont/myfont.css';
```

And I have the following loader configured:

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff2?|otf|jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                name: dev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : '',
                publicPath: path.resolve('src/_next/static/'),
                outputPath: './src/static'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Thankful!

Comment: you cannot do `import {something}  from 'file.CSS'`. It only works with javascript files.

Comment: @MatheusSilva `import {something} from 'file.CSS'` works if you are using CSS Modules.

Comment: @MatheusSilva I am using CSS module and reactjs, I will just get the name of the class, the problem is that there is a font import in this file, I am having a relative path problem.

Comment: Small note: don't use .eot, .svg, or .ttf when you're already loading woff/woff2. eot no longer exists (there are no browsers that support it anymore), svg hasn't been a legal format for years (it was briefly supported until we discovered how insanely bad they were), and ttf is a system font, not an optimised-for-the-web font, and every browser that supports ttf already supports woff, so you're just wasting disk space at best. Just use woff/woff2.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks, man!